# How to upload binary file with ftplib in Python?

Tags: python, ftplib

My python2 script uploads files nicely using this method but python3 is presenting problems and I'm stuck as to where to go next (googling hasn't helped).

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(ftp_host, ftp_user, ftp_pass)
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.txt', open('myfile.txt'))
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/rob3/functions/cli_f.py", line 12, in upload
    ftp.storlines('STOR myfile.txt', open('myfile.txt'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/ftplib.py", line 454, in storbinary
    conn.sendall(buf)
TypeError: must be bytes or buffer, not str
```

I tried altering the code to

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP(ftp_host, ftp_user, ftp_pass)
ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.txt'.encode('utf-8'), open('myfile.txt'))
```

But instead I got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables/rob3/functions/cli_f.py", line 12, in upload
    ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.txt'.encode('utf-8'), open('myfile.txt'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/ftplib.py", line 450, in storbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/ftplib.py", line 358, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/ftplib.py", line 329, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    self.putcmd(cmd)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/ftplib.py", line 179, in putcmd
    self.putline(line)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/lib/python3.1/ftplib.py", line 172, in putline
    line = line + CRLF
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction

Comment: there is nothing py3k-exclusive about this question.

Comment: It's not py3k exclusive but going by how the same code suddenly threw an error (and based on your answer it was right to do so) related to string encoding I assumed it might be.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The issue is not with the command argument, but with the the file object. Since you're storing binary you need to open file with `'rb'` flag:

```
>>> ftp.storbinary('STOR myfile.txt', open('myfile.txt', 'rb'))
'226 File receive OK.'
```

Comment: At work at the moment, will test it out when I get home and hopefully all will be grand, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**APPEND** to file in FTP.

**Note:** *it's not SFTP - FTP only*

```
import ftplib
ftp = ftplib.FTP('localhost')
ftp.login ('user','password')
fin = open ('foo.txt', 'r')
ftp.storbinary ('APPE foo2.txt', fin, 1)
```

Ref: [Thanks to Noah](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-December/037284.html)