# Is Django and ftplib connection posible?

Tags: python, django, ftplib

I am trying to upload a file from a Django server to another FTP Server using ftplib

This is what I am trying to do in views.py

```
@background(schedule=1)
def uploadToFTP(folder):
    """
    Async function to upload the images to FTP Server. 
    """
    print("-------------------Start FTP ----------------------------")
    #establish ftp connection

    ftp = FTP(conf_settings.FTP_DOMAIN,conf_settings.FTP_USER, conf_settings.FTP_PASSWORD)

    file = os.path.join(folder, filename)
    
                
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, file,102400)     # send the file
```

I am getting all sorts of errors like this:

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, file,102400)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/ftplib.py", line 489, in storbinary
    buf = fp.read(blocksize)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

So I have tried many methods, but nothing works. Is this even posible.

I also tried like this:

```
with Image.open(os.path.join(folder, i)) as file:
                
                b = io.BytesIO()
                file.save(b, "JPEG")
                b.seek(0)
                #upload activity
                
                ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + i, file,102400)
```

Still not successful

Comment: `file` has to be an open file handle, not the path to a file.

Comment: Hi Klaus D. check out the edit, is this what you mean by an open file handle? It also creates error

Comment: Trying to catch the error, I got this response, "error 200 Type set to I"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Here is a [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) that you should check first
2. Here is a [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911754/how-to-upload-binary-file-with-ftplib-in-python) that you should check second
3. Here is an example of correct code:

   ```py
   from ftplib import FTP

   with FTP(
     conf_settings.FTP_DOMAIN,
     conf_settings.FTP_USER,
     conf_settings.FTP_PASSWORD
   ) as ftp:
     with open(os.path.join(folder, filename), 'rb') as file:
       ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {filename}', file)
   ```